# How to make a search with 'OR' condition in Kibana

Tags: json, search, elasticsearch, kibana

I am searching for strings `"abcd" OR "zyx" OR "something"` in my **Kibana (Version 4.5.4**)

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "abcd",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any easy way to change the query to search for all ?

I tried the code below and some other way.. But not able to get a correct answer.

```
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "text": 
        [
         {
            "query": "abcd",
            "type": "phrase"
          },
          {
            "query": "zyx",
            "type": "phrase"
          }
        ]

        }
      }
    }
```

Expecting an easy way !!!

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index.. `GET index/type/_mapping`

Comment: I am using client. I can't get the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below queries.

In case your `text` field is a `not-analyzed` field. Following Query will work..

```
{
"query": {
    "terms": {
       "text": [
          "abc",
          "zyx",
          "something"
          ]
      }
    }
 }
```

In case `text` field is an `analyzed` one using `standard-analyzer`, following should work :

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
           {
               "match": {
                  "text": "abc"
               }
           } ,
           {
            "match": {
                  "text": "zyx"
               }
           },
           {
                "match": {
                  "text": "something"
               }
           }
        ]
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Richa . I will try this and reply back